# mysql left join doesnt returns rows from joined table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have 2 identical tables (_impressionsdaily, _impressionsalltime), at the end of every day i move all the data from daily to alltime.
The structure is: ID, purchaseID, impression, unique, date.

I run the following query:

```
SELECT  
    daily.purchaseID,
    SUM(daily.impression + IFNULL(alltime.impression, 0)) AS impression,
    SUM(daily.unique + IFNULL(alltime.unique, 0)) AS `unique`
    FROM _impressionsdaily daily
    LEFT JOIN _impressionsalltime alltime ON alltime.purchaseID= daily.purchaseID
    GROUP BY daily.purchaseID;
```

The thing is that if the alltime table has purchases that are not available in the daily i wont see them.

Basically the idea is to sum all impressions for both daily and alltime.

---EDIT
The thing is at 12:00am everyday the daily table is copied to the alltime and then deleted.
so the solution given are wrong..

Thanks for the Help,
Danny

Comment: Are the records in the daily table replicated to the alltime table constantly? or on a timed-based, so that alltime is out-of-sync with daily? If they're out-of-sync, you'd need to do an outer join of some sort, because an inner/left/right join will only find the records that exist in either table, or both tables.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: I'm familiar with union...just needed @SeamWM way of thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [Union Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID), p.purchaseID
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM _impressionsdaily
      UNION SELECT *
      FROM _impressionsalltime) AS p
GROUP BY p.purchaseID
```

Comment: add SUM*...i was missing that in my previous response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
daily.purchaseID,
SUM(daily.impression + IFNULL(alltime.impression, 0)) AS impression,
SUM(daily.unique + IFNULL(alltime.unique, 0)) AS `unique`
FROM _impressionsdaily daily
LEFT JOIN _impressionsalltime alltime ON alltime.purchaseID= daily.purchaseID
GROUP BY daily.purchaseID;
```

In this case you haven't selected any field form _impressionsalltime table.

You can use this sql to select field from _impressionsalltime table as well

```
SELECT  
alltime.*,
daily.purchaseID,
SUM(daily.impression + IFNULL(alltime.impression, 0)) AS impression,
SUM(daily.unique + IFNULL(alltime.unique, 0)) AS `unique`
FROM _impressionsdaily daily
LEFT JOIN _impressionsalltime alltime ON alltime.purchaseID= daily.purchaseID
GROUP BY daily.purchaseID;
```

Comment: this isn't right since the result of this query will only return the left side of the result as NULLS...